# htaccess password protection keeps asking for password on subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following in my htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing

AuthUserFile /home/html/.htpasswd
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

It works great in the root directory...

The problem is when I access a sub-directory, it asks for a password again. For each and every sub-directory it asks for a password. In fact, everytime I refresh it asks for the password again, instead of caching it in.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you want it to even ask for a password in your sub-directories?

Comment: I want the sub directories to be password controlled by the parent directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this one out. It is related to FancyIndexing. If you have FancyIndexing enabled, htaccess will ask to reconfirm the password on every file and folder within the initial folder. Turning this off solved the issue.